# Take array of values and defined function and generate an array of functions with each containing the respective values

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to take an array of values, and generate an array of functions with the argument of said function being populated by each initial array item. For example...

```
const IDs = [001, 002, 003]
const getEmpData = (id) => { fetch(`companysite.com/data/user eq '${id}'`) }
// Code to generate below array
[
  fetch(`companysite.com/data/user eq '001'`),
  fetch(`companysite.com/data/user eq '002'`),
  fetch(`companysite.com/data/user eq '003'`)
]
```

This is a very simplified version of a problem I'm trying to solve, which may not even be the ideal thing to do - but I was curious if this was an actual pattern. I would take the resulting array, chunk it, and then put it into a reduce method to make batches of API requests.

Comment: The current desired result already makes the API requests. If you don't want code to execute directly you should store it in a function. Did you mean to get `[() => fetch(\`companysite.com/data/user eq '001'\`), ...]` as the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

- replace the `console.log` in below to required function

```js
const IDs = [001, 002, 003]
// returns a function which can be invoked lazily when needed
const getFunction = (someData) => () => console.log(someData);
// the array of functions for all `IDs`
const functions = IDs.map(x => getFunction(x));
// optionally running all the `functions`
//    replace forEach with `map` if you wish to collect the resultant array from the function invocations
functions.forEach(functionToRun => functionToRun());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need *code* but just an array of functions, you can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
const IDs = [001, 002, 003];
const getEmpData = (id) => fetch(`companysite.com/data/user eq '${id}'`);
const getters = IDs.map(id => getEmpData.bind(null, id);
```

Now `getters` will be an array of functions that accept no arguments and return the `fetch` promise.

And if what you actually need is an array of promises you want to resolve to results, you can use `Promise.all(IDs.map(getEmpData))`...

Comment: This is great! And you are correct, what I need is an array of promises I want to resolve. More specifically, I want to chunk the array of functions and run them in serial inside of a reduce method. I'll work on figuring that part out. Thank you very much.

Comment: The promises will begin resolving immediately. If you don't want that, https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit is nice enough for limiting concurrency